# how to convert a struct converted to const char (c++) to struct objective-c

Tags: c++, objective-c, struct, udp

I have a struct like so

```
struct myStruct
{
    UInt8 _foo;
    float _bar[3];
    float _fooBar[3];
} _ThisIsMyStruct;
```

in my c++ code. This is cast to a const char:

```
char* sendThisStuff = static_cast<char*>(static_cast<void*>(& _ThisIsMyStruct));
```

and then sent to my iOS app via udp. I'm using GCDAsyncUdpSocket on the client side to receive the udp packet. This gives me an NSData object. 
My problem is now how to get that back into that same struct.

ETA:
I tried

myStruct debugStruct;
[data getBytes:&debugStruct length:sizeof(debugStruct)];

Comment: Can you provide objective-C code whatever to tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSData* data;
myStruct* myStructPtr = (myStruct*)data.bytes;
```

Have in mind, that myStructPtr will become invalid pointer, when data will be deallocated.